# How to pile up several DIV's in a given total height, with vertical scrolling on one DIV (w/o JS)

Tags: html, css, height, overflow

I have a 3-parts page : 1 heading part that must be always visible and at top of viewport, 1 content part that must be scrollable, 1 trailing part that must be always visible and at bottom of viewport.

I do not want tu use any JS, nor Expression. I have found many answers to do that with only CSS, but all assume that the header and trailer's heights are constant and known, which is **not** my case.

My idea is still to play with height and overflow attribs on the BODY and DIVs, so that one of the DIVs can be made scrollable, with the maximum available display height. 
But so far could not find a working solution.

I have tried this (with just 2 parts, header and content) :

```
<body style="overflow: hidden; height: 100vh">
<div id="MyHeader"> blablabla </div>
<div id="MyContent" style="overflow: scroll;">
<P>Many lines of content ...</P>
</div>
```

I do see the v-scroll bar on the content DIV but it is full-height and uneffective, so I simply can't see its overflowing part.

Note: If this is not the right way I could consider using a 1-col table, with total height set to 100vh and one cell made v-scrollable. But I have seen that is more tricky, and may have side effects on some browsers....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `position:sticky` property? I think it can actually fit your case, [here is a good read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) on positioning of elements in HTML documents.

```css
header, footer {position:sticky; background:#ccc}
header {top:0}
footer {bottom:0}
```

```html
<header>
<H1>Any height header block</H1>
</header>
<article>
<p>I'll be scrollable article</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p>I'll be scrollable article</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p>I'll be scrollable article</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p>I'll be scrollable article</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</article>
<footer>
<H2>Any height footer block</H2>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by position `sticky` 
Set header and footer to position sticky with `top: 0` for header and `bottom: 0` for footer.

Here is an example:
https://codepen.io/itsashis4u/pen/ZEEEKwq